# Accessing data in a DataTable from a button click within a row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I can access the data row by the following simple method:

```
$('#received-body tr').click( function(){
    aData = received_table.fnGetData(this);
    selected_received_id = aData[0];
    alert( selected_received_id );
});
```

but I can't access them from the button called `.received-update` in one of the rows:

```
$('#received-body .received-update').click( function(){
    alert( 'update' ); // works
    aData = received_table.fnGetData( $(this).parents('tr')); // fails
    selected_received_id = aData[0];
    alert( 'update:' + selected_received_id );                      
});
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: which error comes up or trying using console.log to get error

Answer (score 4):

You can solve your problem by replacing

```
    aData = received_table.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr'));
```

with

```
    aData = received_table.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0]);
```

This same syntax is also required for calls to `received_table.fnGetPosition()`

Answer (score 1):

Below piece of code will help,

```
var table = $('#tableID').DataTable();
var row_data;
$('#tableID tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
    row_data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    console.log(row_data); // you will get the row data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use closest as [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) might be giving more then one rows. While closest get the first match up the DOM hierarchy.

```
aData = recieved_table.fnGetData($(this).closest('tr')); // fails
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work 
'code'
TypeError: a.nodeName is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

..._DT_Input).val(a)}catch(o){h(b[c]._DT_Input).val(a)}}}else h.extend(g.aoPreSearc...
'code'

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or add html you have?

Answer (score 0):

```
aData = recieved_table.fnGetData($(this).parent('tr'));
```

Try `.parent()` instead of `.parents()` because `.parents()` get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements. `.parent()` will only work if the tr is a direct children of the tr. In that scenario `.closest()` will be ideal as shown below.

```
aData = recieved_table.fnGetData($(this).closest('tr'));
```

If above didn't work out for you, try [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to reduce the set of matched elements.

Comment: parent gives me this error...
'code'
TypeError: a.nodeName is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

..._DT_Input).val(a)}catch(o){h(b[c]._DT_Input).val(a)}}}else h.extend(g.aoPreSearc...

jquery....min.js (line 105)
'code'