# How do i retrieve data and display it in a modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, datatables

I currently have a table of data that has been presented using DataTables. When i click on an item, i want a modal dialog to display with custom content based on the row selected. Each row is going to have a link to open the modal. How do i go about achieving this?

One solution that im thinking about is to do a post back to the site and retrieve a json object. And some how bind the details to the mo

Comment: Check this page https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/10817/click-a-row-and-call-javascript-function 

And to display the modal just call it like you would do
 $('#modalId').modal('show');

Comment: it may also help to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437625/accessing-data-in-a-datatable-from-a-button-click-within-a-row in terms on 'how to retreive data' from your datatable with a button

Comment: how about using jquery?? No need to postback!!